# different color and size but same price. configurable product needed?

Tags: product, attributes

I've both color and size attribute but no change in price.

What method I've to follow if the product just need to list the color and size as drop down in front end and need to be imported these attributes as I upload product csv.

Need to add it as configurable product? Is there any other option?

Comment: If you want to manage the stocks for size/color variations then Yes you have to make it configurable.

Comment: @MagePsycho Thank you for your help. But I need help in importing configurable products, as I tried it in many way, But configurable product and attributes never imported. :(

Comment: Magento doesn't support import of configurable product by default. Either you have to use third party extension for importing configurable or have to import simple products via import profile and configurable products manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use you can create product in either of below format

1. `Simple Product` with `Custom Options`(size and color)
2. `Configurable Product`

You better go with `configurable product`. This is because configurable products are actually intended to use for these type of situations. The same can obtain using `custom options`. However there are some limitations for that. When consider management of `stock`, `inventory` etc, configurable product is much reliable than any other options in this case.

So in my opinion, you go with configurable products.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I need help in importing configurable products, as I tried it in many way, But configurable product and attributes never imported. :(

Comment: Same case but the different price, how to configure the products?@Rajeev K Tomy

Comment: @Gem that is pretty straight forward. You can specify the price in the configurable option section. Please go through the documentation of Magento if you have any doubts on this. I am not sure about the Magento version you are asking about though